# Assign and update entity property in Symfony2 form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Is there anyway I can assign an entity and edit one of it's properties in a single Symfony2 form?

Example:

Tasks have many Activities.

When I create an Activity I assign a Task through an Entity form field. I also want to update the Task remainingEstimateInSeconds when the entity is created.

Activity Entity:

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

/**
 * Activity
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ActivityRepository")
 */
class Activity
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Task")
     */
    private $task;
}
```

Task Entity:

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Task
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\TaskRepository")
 */
class Task
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="remainingEstimateInSeconds", type="integer", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $remainingEstimateInSeconds;
}
```

Activity Form:

My current implementation is using a non-mapped field. The remaining estimate is set back onto the task in the controller which isn't the best implementation.

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotNull;

class ActivityType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('description');
        $builder->add('task');
        $builder->add('remainingEstimateInSeconds', 'integer', array(
            'mapped' => false,
            'constraints' => array(
                new NotNull()
            )
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Activity',
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'activity';
    }
}
```

I also tried using `property_path => "task.remainingEstimateInSeconds"` but the duplicate `property_path` was throwing some kind of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using a non-mapped field with POST_SET_DATA and POST_SUBMIT listeners on the main form to prepopulate the field/update the object?

Comment: Ok so pretty much what I have now but using events. I was hoping that It was something I could do just with property_path. I'll work on implementing the events tomorrow. Thanks for the hint :)

Comment: I ended up also needing PRE_SET_DATA to show the value for editing an Activity.